# Observable collection not updating listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I am using an observable collection as an item source for my WPF listbox. In code this means:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<AssetBrowserFilePreviewElement> mLastElements; // = new ...

private void OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    mBrowser.SelectedFilesListView.ItemsSource = mLastElements;
}

// in another method:
mLastElements.Clear();
foreach(var elem in elements)
    mLastElements.Add(elem);
```

(OnInitialized gets called and elements is not empty)

As written in the title my problem is that adding and removing items from the collection has absolutely no effect on the listbox, it always remains empty. If I bind the `IEnumerable<AssetBrowserFilePreviewElement> elements` as ItemsSource instead of this Clear and Add-loop i get the expected results. In this case it would work this way but in other methods i want to selectively remove or add items and therefore I need the observable collection to work.

What else do I have to do to propagate modifications to the collection to the listbox?

**EDIT:**
As suggested in the response I've created a property and a binding in XAML but still no response whatsoever.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Padding="10,10,10,10" x:Name="SelectedFilesListView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentFiles}">
```

C#:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<AssetBrowserFilePreviewElement> mCurFiles = new ObservableCollection<AssetBrowserFilePreviewElement>();
public ObservableCollection<AssetBrowserFilePreviewElement> CurrentFiles { get { return mCurFiles; } }


CurrentFiles.Clear();
foreach(var elem in elements)
    CurrentFiles.Add(elem);
```

CurrentFiles getter gets called when the control loads. The method that modifies the collection gets called as well, elements.Count == 18, no visual change.

**EDIT 2:**
I have added a test element to CurrentFiles in the constructor of AssetBrowserViewModel (where the Property is defined and which is set as DataContext). This item shows up, but modifying the elements of the collection keeps showing that test element.

Comment: Show your XAML please, also show the **Property** which is used in the Binding.

Comment: Did you set the `DataContext = this;` on your constructor?

Comment: Yes, its set to `DataContext = new AssetBrowserViewModel(this);` which has the `CurrentFiles` property. I guess it wouldnt call the getter of the `CurrentFiles` property if it wasnt? Because thats usually how i debug if the context is set correctly, so if it werent thatd be good to know ;)

Comment: I have added a test element to the collection before the control loads. It shows this element correctly but when i modify the collection it doesnt update the control, it keeps showing said test element.

Comment: Can you findout the stacktrace if the code behind is calling the getter or the xaml binding?
I suggest turning on some WPF Trace Settings: Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings > Data Binding.

So it doesn't react on changed events...

Comment: Yes, the stack trace is: `CurrentFiles.get()`, `PropertyPathWorker.GetValue`, `PropertyPathWorker.RawValue`, `ClrBindingWorker.RawValue`, `BindingExpression.TransferValue`, and so on.

Comment: I recommend you to start new project with only `ListBox`, `CurrentFiles` and binding. Then make a button to change something in `CurrentFiles` (e.g. add new item). If that works, when you know right way and are good to find why it doesn't works for you. If not - you prepare good [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently you are doing mistake *somewhere*, because it should work as it is shown.

Comment: Are you positively sure that your code which modifies the collection is acting on the same view model instance as the one that was put into the DataContext? Your assignment `DataContext = new AssetBrowserViewModel(this)` implies that you would later access that instance by something like `((AssetBrowserViewModel)DataContext).SetCurrentFiles()` or so.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, thats exactly how im accessing it. `var viewModel = DataContext as AssetBrowserViewModel; viewModel.Handle_BrowserSelectionChanged(AssetTreeView.SelectedItem as AssetBrowserDirectory);`. Just to be sure I added a log message to the AssetBrowserViewModel constructor and it only gets called once.

Comment: @Sinatr While I agree that minimal examples are all fun and games i think its pretty useless in this case. We already asserted, that the minimal example **should** work and reducing it to the minimal example therefore will work. Creating a minimal example that includes the error is the same thing as actually finding the error in which case i neither need the minimal example nor this posting.

Comment: And you have also debugged into the `Handle_BrowserSelectionChanged` method to verify that the code is actually executed, e.g. that `AssetTreeView.SelectedItem as AssetBrowserDirectory` is non-null? In my understanding, the SelectedItem should be an `AssetBrowserFilePreviewElement` (which is the collection element type), and not an `AssetBrowserDirectory`.

Comment: Yes, ive verified that its called and ive verified that elements.Count > 0. If I check CurrentFiles in the Debugger it also shows the added values. The SelectionChanged is handled in a TreeView selection changed event where directories are which should cause the listbox to show the files of that directory. the SelectedItem is from the TreeView not from the ListBox.

Comment: Yes, there is only one instance of the view model ever created (according to the constructor log).

Comment: @Cromon, it's good you solved it. What I mean when offering you to create mcve is [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck) technique. While doing *simple stuff* (or simplifying complicated, e.i. preparing mcve) you may suddenly find a small, but a significant difference from your code. And often that is a reason of the problem too. If however the problem still, then you have *proof*, which you can show to others. Several times I started to post question here, then realized what I need an example, started preparing mcve and suddenly found the problem (thus not asked question).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you simply set `ItemSource` once. There is no mechanism which tracks changes.

Instead you need a **Binding** (preferably in XAML).

This will listen to the `PropertyChanged` events of the `ObservableColletion` and update the `ListBox` accordingly.

Comment: While this seems to be a rather strange concept (why cant the setter of ItemsSource check what kind of collection you add?) it also didnt solve my problem. I'll add the new C# and XAML code in a second to my original posting.

Comment: There is nothing strange about it. It is simply the WPF way of doing it. If really needed it can be done in code as well by creating a Binding object.

Comment: @Cromon, wpf prefers binding. Without binding **you can subscribe** to [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) and update `ListBox` content if you prefer.

Comment: When it comes to registering for the `CollectionChanged` (not `PropertyChanged`) event of the source collection, it doesn't make any difference if you bind the `ItemsSource` property, or if you set it in code behind. Even if you set `ItemsSource` in code behind, the ListBox will register a CollectionChanged handler, as long as the source collection implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. So OP's observation is correct. This doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very well, after all it was just a stupid mistake caused by Resharper. It decided to import ObservableCollection from SharpDX.Collections instead of System.Collections.ObjectModel. I realized it when checking the subscription on the CollectionChanged event and there was no CollectionChanged event.

Also a binding is not required. Setting `ItemsSource` in code behind to a private field and modifying that collection works like a charm (as does a binding).